# How to change OS's downloading configurations?

Tags: configuration, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

I want to change my Ubuntu OS's downloading configuration so that it downloads software from a local area repository.  How can I do this?  I'm using a virtual machine

Answer (score 0):

you should prepare your local repository and bring deb and deb-src in

```
    /etc/apt/sources.list
```